# mat-grid-list with a mat-card and mat-card-actions/mat-card-footer

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I have the following code, in angular 6 and material design:

```
<div class="grid-container">

  <h1 class="mat-h1">Candidatos</h1>

  <mat-grid-list cols="5" gutterSize="20px" class="list-candidatos">

    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let candidato of candidatos">

      <mat-card class="candidato-card">

        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>{{candidato.nome}}</mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>

        <mat-card-content>
          &nbsp;
        </mat-card-content>

        <mat-card-actions>
          <button mat-button>Edit</button>
        </mat-card-actions>

      </mat-card>

    </mat-grid-tile>

  </mat-grid-list>

</div>
```

And the css

```
.list-candidatos {
  width: 93%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.candidato-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But no matter what I change in the css I was not able to make the mat-card-actions or the mat-card-footer keep in the bottom of card.
So:

1. The structure is right or is missing something?
2. If its right, how to put the mat-card-actions/mat-card-footer in the bottom of mat-grid-tile?

Comment: Have you imported MatCardModule? Your example code looks fine but it doesn't include the mat-card-footer so this is probably not your real code. Create a working StackBlitz example or at least post all your actual code.

Comment: The piece of code I put only contains the mat-card-actions, but I tried with mat-card-footer and neither look to work. Sorry about the confusion#

Comment: Just in case, I create: https://angular-xtf5eq.stackblitz.io

To code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtf5eq

Comment: Footer is in the correct position if you don't use `height: 100%` on the `mat-card`s. It might be a bug. I don't think there is anything 'wrong' with your code other than using height on the cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in CSS , it will solve the footer issue

```
.mat-card{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mat-card-header {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mat-card-content{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a `mat-card` (with or without footer,image or header) or a custom component which use `mat-card` with `fxFlex` value inside a `div` or whatever element with `fxLayout="row wrap` like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <mat-card *ngFor="let obj of objects" fxFlex="50">{{obj}}</mat-card>
</div>
```

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995971/creating-grid-of-cards-dynamically-using-angular-material-2/55431231#55431231)